# Serve ssh connection to wifi devices while connected to a wifi network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, openssh

I was wondering if there's any way for a laptop to be both simultaneously connected to a wireless network, while at the same time acting as an ad-hoc network with local access to serve as a wifi connection for my mobile device, which would be ssh-ing into the laptop and using local resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without two wireless cards, no. In general, a single wireless radio can either be joined to an existing network, or be broadcasting an ad-hoc network, not both. With two wireless cards, however, it'd most definitely be possible.